# How to stretch image without losing clarity

Tags: image, stretch, clarity

How do I stretch a image without losing clarity?

I am using

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="width:1100px">
        <img src="Images/X.jpg" style="width:1100px">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If I change 1100px to 100% will the image look bad?

Appreciate your help

Thanks,
Ravi Ramaswamy

Comment: You need a better quality image!

Comment: What are the original dimensions of the image?

Comment: 1340px width and 360px height